# .+ cookie org mode repeated task misbehaviour

Tags: org-mode

My problem:

After changing the following TODO to done (C-c C-t)

```
* TODO Workout
  SCHEDULED: <2014-02-20 Mon .+1w>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :STYLE: habit
  :END:
```

the TODO changes to (today is 2014-02-24)

```
* TODO Workout
  SCHEDULED: <2014-02-24 Mon .+1w>
  - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2014-02-24 Mon 23:20]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :STYLE:    habit
  :LAST_REPEAT: [2014-02-24 Mon 23:20]
  :END:
```

The TODO has been scheduled to today and appears in my agenda. I was expecting it to be scheduled to today+(1 week).
No matter how often I finish this TODO, it is always scheduled to today.

What has to be changed to achieve the expected behavior?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it is correctly scheduled for next Tuesday (I just executed it now):

```
* TODO Workout
  SCHEDULED: <2014-03-04 Tue .+1w>
  :LOGBOOK:
  - State "DONE"        ->  "DONE"       [2014-02-25 Tue 09:18]
  :END:
  :PROPERTIES:
  :STYLE: habit
  :LAST_REPEAT: [2014-02-25 Tue 09:18]
  :END:
```

Try to reproduce the problem with Emacs -Q. If you succeed, report the problem to the Org mode ML. If you don't, you should find your problem in your config by dichotomy...

Comment: For your information, my Emacs / Org mode configuration is public at https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven.

Comment: Removing the following 3 lines from my .emacs did the trick: (require 'org)
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'org-modules "org-habit")

Comment: I would advice you to make a minimal Emacs configuration file, and a minimal Org file, showing the problem you expose, and to send that to the Org mode ML. Because deleting the 3 lines above (in particular the last one) is NOT a no-op... It seems to me to be a bug which, then, should be fixed.